# Establish a Lync/Skype for business IM Chat from a website (Intranet)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, lync-2013, ucma, ucwa, skype-for-business

We need to develop a website in Asp.net MVC 4 which will connect user within the organisation on Lync or (skype for business now):The ask is:

1) A Sales guy see 10 Technical person in the list which is in database and all of them are in AD if that helps

2) A sales guy click on an icon to connect to a technical person, a lync window appears on client machine (We can assume that all client will have Lync or skype for business up and running on their system from where they will access website)

3) A lync window appears on the machine of a person we are trying to connect to with Default text "hi! Bla Bla Bla"

Can somebody point me to the correct implementation with some set up details from infrastructure POV as well. We tried to do that but that does not work when we deploy to server:

```
AutomationModalities conversationModes = 0;
Dictionary<AutomationModalitySettings, object> conversationSettings =
            new Dictionary<AutomationModalitySettings, object>();
        conversationModes = AutomationModalities.InstantMessage;
             conversationSettings.Add(AutomationModalitySettings.FirstInstantMessage, "Hi This is a call XXXXXXn");
        conversationSettings.Add(AutomationModalitySettings.SendFirstInstantMessageImmediately, true);'
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it appears you cannot touch the cross-domain authorization list (white-list), you should be able to achieve what you are looking for by writing some non-JavaScript code to communicate with UCWA.  There are a few articles on MSDN that demonstrate how to communicate with UCWA using C#/.NET which might prove interesting:

- [Lync 2013: Create UCWA Windows Store apps using C#/XAML and XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/Dn551186.aspx)
- [Set up the UCWA event channel to receive incoming notifications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn683882.aspx)
- [Making an outgoing IM call and sending messages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn756469.aspx)
- [Answer an incoming IM call and receive messages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn771762.aspx)

It gives the basics of handling authentication, interacting with the events channel, handling incoming IM calls and messages.  It is designed to handle XML, but that could be changed to work with JSON.

Comment: Thanks I will Try and get back

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Skype Web SDK for this - Microsoft have a bunch of examples on their site for the SDK.

http://developer.skype.com/

or more specifically

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn962160%28v=office.16%29.aspx

It's a JavaScript library, but very easy to integrate with a .NET MVC or Forms app.

I also have some tutorials on exactly this on my blog but not if it's appropriate to post that here. :)

Comment: As long as it helps and you disclose that it's your own blog you're linking to it's fine.

Comment: Hi I have referred the one using UCMA, approach i can not implement that as the Lync Server team in my organisation is not allowing to white list the Request URL in Lync Sever , is there any any alternate to UCMA approach?

Comment: In the event that you cannot touch the white list you can write any non-JavaScript code to get around the cross-domain authorization list.

Comment: Hi @matthew Can you please direct me to any POC or a sample which helps me in opening a Lync Window from my web application

Comment: I've got some tutorials on my web site (https://www.matthewproctor.com/skype-web-sdk-tutorials/), and there are some great IM examples on the Skype developer site http://developer.skype.com/ under Skype Web SDK.